# How to traverse/loop through each cell of particular COLUMN of DevExpress.GridView.gridcontrol in C# WinForm Application..?

Tags: c#

I want to traverse through **each cell of particular (Known) column** of DevExpress.GridView.gridcontrol to put some validation depending on particular cell value, as of now what I have tried is as follows--

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
     this.gridView1.Columns[i].AppearanceCell.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Using above code **I can can loop through each column** of DevExpress.GridView.gridcontrol but **unable to loop through each cell of particular (i-th) column**. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Please help.. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: this should help: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q275948

Comment: this.gridView1.Columns[i].Cells[j] cant you access a cell of a row like this?

Comment: @user3596113 It not possible..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer it is done by using RowCellStyle event as follows--

```
private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView View = sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;

            if (e.Column.FieldName == "XYZ")
            {               
                string strCellValue = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["XYZ"]);
                int inStockCol = e.RowHandle;
                if (!strCellValue.Equals("NA"))
                {
                    double dblCellValue = Convert.ToDouble(strCellValue);

                    if (dblCellValue < 0 || dblCellValue > 1000)
                    {
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.LightPink;                      

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.LightGreen;
                    }
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of that in the reference:

[Validating rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument749)

[Conditional Style Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2406)

[GridView.RowStyle Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic)

[GridView.RowCellStyle Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic)

And a simple loop:

```
// iterate cells and compose a tab delimited string of cell values
for (int i = 0; i < m_gridView.RowCount; i++)
{
     int rowHandle = m_gridView.GetRowHandle(i);
     ...
}
// and
for(int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
{
     //Do something here
}
```

look also at:
`GridView.GetRowCellValue` method